# Unloading from Redshift to S3 in CSV format doesn't create the .csv file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, export-to-csv, unload

When I unload from Redshift to S3 in CSV format, then when I go the specified path in s3 there isn't any .csv file. The only files I see are the manifest and the 000 file.

The command is the below

```sql
UNLOAD('select distinct * from mytable')
to 's3://my-bucket/data/myfile'
iam_role 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
header
CSV DELIMITER AS '|'
manifest 
allowoverwrite
parallel off
```

The query runs fine and when I go the S3 path I see the below and a hyphen (-) in the type column:

```
myfile000
myfilemanifest
```

Shouldn't there also be a .csv file?

Thanks.

I don't know how to proceed on this.

Comment: The `myfile000` should be in CSV format. It just doesn't have a `.csv` ending. Download it and take a look.

Comment: @pan325, Do you have encryption by any chance? If not, can you try this? 
> The UNLOAD command is designed to use parallel processing. We recommend leaving PARALLEL enabled for most cases, especially if the files will be used to load tables using a COPY command.
```
UNLOAD('select distinct * from mytable')
to 's3://my-bucket/data/myfile'
iam_role 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
delimiter '|'
manifest 
allowoverwrite;
```

Comment: @JohnRotenstein. Yes, I have downloaded and indeed the file is pipeline delimited but hasn't a .csv extension. So the unload command, from what I understand, just creates these two files with no extension.

Comment: @Sri  It is a prerequisite to have the parallel off for some reason and I can't change that.

Answer (score 2):

It's a way how Redshift handles files where it appends `000` to the filename, though if your concern is more to get a `.csv` extension appened to the file name you can do so by adding the `EXTENSION 'extension-name'` option to the `UNLOAD` command

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

So in your case it would be

```sql
UNLOAD
(
'
select distinct * from mytable
'
)

to 's3://my-bucket/data/myfile'
iam_role 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
header
CSV DELIMITER AS '|'
manifest 
allowoverwrite
parallel off 
EXTENSION '.csv'
```

Comment: Thanks @DataWrangler. So the 000 even if I have parallel off and all data are in one file it is default and there isn't a way to avoid it.

Comment: Nope, upto my knowledge as Redshift is designed to handle data parallely so the design decision to have a numeric `000` that gets incremented for each files. 

```
The UNLOAD command is designed to use parallel processing. We recommend leaving PARALLEL enabled for most cases, especially if the files are used to load tables using a COPY command.
```